# gpg: signing failed: No pinentry

Tags: macos, gnupg

Im trying to setup my gnupg configuration on MAC OS 11.2.1

So far I have setup my SSH, I have generated my GPG key and added it into GPG agent.

Now, if I run this command:

```
 echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

I am getting this result:

```
   -----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

test
gpg: signing failed: No pinentry
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: No pinentry
```

The problem is, that the pinetry is installed:

```
pinentry-curses (pinentry) 1.1.1
Copyright (C) 2016 g10 Code GmbH
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

In my gpg-agent.conf file, I have this line:

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
```

In my gpg.conf I have this line:

```
no-tty
```

gpg version:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.2
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /Users/usr/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

I have tried to kill gpg agent and reinstall gnupg several times, reinstal pinentry. Nothing helped.

Update
I have tried

```
unset DISPLAY
```

Still no help

Comment: you're in the wrong place. stackoverflow is for programming questions and https://superuser.com is for generic computer stuff

Comment: Ah damn, thanks and Im sorry.